# Spring BeanPostProcessor BeanCreationException runtime error

Tags: spring

I'm unable to launch hello world app with Spring 4.3.6 Please, help, I don't even know what may be wrong.
Without bean `messageService` and `aop` section everything works. But I got this error with config as it is

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'printer' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#c273d3' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#c273d3': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1423665' of type [org.springframework.aop.config.MethodLocatingFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1423665': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [MessagePrinterService] for bean with name 'messageService' defined in class path resource [config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MessagePrinterService
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [MessagePrinterService] for bean with name 'messageService' defined in class path resource [config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MessagePrinterService
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'printer' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#c273d3' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#c273d3': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1423665' of type [org.springframework.aop.config.MethodLocatingFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1423665': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [MessagePrinterService] for bean with name 'messageService' defined in class path resource [config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MessagePrinterService
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [MessagePrinterService] for bean with name 'messageService' defined in class path resource [config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MessagePrinterService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
```

Xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

   <bean id="printer" class="helloword.MessagePrinter">
      <constructor-arg ref="message"></constructor-arg>
   </bean>

    <bean id="message" class="helloword.HelloWordMessage">
        <constructor-arg value="Hello Spring World!"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageService" class="MessagePrinterService">
    </bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="messageService">
            <aop:pointcut id="print" expression="execution(* *.print(..))"/>
            <aop:before pointcut-ref="print" method="preMsg"/>
            <aop:after pointcut-ref="print" method="postMsg"/>
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

Classes, all is separate files:

```
    public class HelloWordMessage implements Message{

        private String msg;

        public HelloWordMessage(String s) {
            msg = s;
        }

        @Override
        public String getText() {
            return msg;     
        }

    }

public class MessagePrinter implements Printer {
    private Message msg;

    public MessagePrinter(Message m){
        msg = m;

    }

    @Override
    public void print(){
        System.out.println(msg.getText());
    }

}

public class MessagePrinterService {

    public MessagePrinterService(){
        System.out.println("MessagePrinterService created");    
    }

    public void preMsg(){
        System.out.println("Message alert!:");
    }

    public void postMsg(){
        System.out.println("End of message.");
    }
}

public class Aplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml"); 
        MessagePrinter printer = context.getBean(MessagePrinter.class);
        printer.print();
        context.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MessagePrinterService

Spring cannot load the class MessagePrinterService.

Put it into a specific package and change the configuration accordingly. It should work then.

Comment: It's in a package with all other classes. And how configuration should look like than?

Comment: In your configuration, you have the following line <bean id="messageService" class="MessagePrinterService"> which is not cosidering any package, it should be class="helloworld.MessagePrinterService"

Comment: Thanks for response. Now I have different error "Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [helloword.MessagePrinter] is defined: expected single bean but found 0: " in line "context.getBean(...) in main method in class Application". Bean printer present in context but it type is "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy" How to fix this?

Comment: You have something which is not present in your question. If you try to get the bean through the interface (context.getBean(Printer.class)), it will work as expected.

Comment: Still not working, got runtime error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2 cannot be cast to helloword.MessagePrinter. Without casting it produce compilation error. After commenting out aop section in config program works, but error was caused by MessagePrinter which is still there.

Comment: As I said, you didn't include something in the question. Spring is creating a Proxy object based on your interface, that's why you get the exception. In order to use your Printer, it doesn't have to be a MessagePrinter. Use it through the interface. `Printer printer = context.getBean(Printer.class);
        printer.print();`